# Is there a faster way to create alternating row colors with xlwings than by looping over the rows?

Tags: python-3.7, xlwings

This creates a 1.000 rows and 20 columns area with alternating colors, starting from the upper left cell of a `named_range` in sheet `sht`:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('FileName.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
first_row = sht.range('NamedRange').row
first_column = sht.range('NamedRange').column

for row in range(first_row, (first_row + 999)):
    if (row % 2) == 0:
        sht.range((row, first_column), (row, (first_column + 19))).color = (198, 224, 180)
    else:
        sht.range((row, first_column), (row, (first_column + 19))).color = (226, 239, 218)
```

The result is fine, but the procedure is really slow, at least on a Mac (where xlwings' communication is slower than on a Windows machine). Plus Looping over each single row is an undignified enterprise. Any idea how to speed it up, and possibly how to make use of the named range for that, other than only for getting start values for the loop?

**ANSWER**

There is no xlwings functionality of dealing with single cells, rows or columns apart from adressing them individually with one of the known ways allowed for by the [Range][1] class.

It is however possible to use Excel's conditional formatting (twice, if you want to format even and uneven rows) by letting it check for two conditions combined with a rule of the form

=AND((formatting rule);(Excel content incorporating rule from python app)

Formatting rule e.g. =MOD(ROW(),2)=0 for even and =MOD(ROW(),2)=1 for uneven rows. Excel content incorporating rule from python app could be anything, in my case I wanted to change formatting if the Excel cells contain formulae rather than values, so

=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0;ISFORMULA($A$1))

Comment: Would Excel Tables work for you? They color alternate rows by default.

Comment: I need to change the alternating color scheme based on some logic in the app, thus "static" Excel doesn't help - from xlwings, you can't set "Format as Table" and select "Banded Columns", can you? However your hint has gotten me to another, related idea, since alternating rows can also be done with conditional formatting. Writing a flag to some Excel cell and making the formatting of a range conditional will do.

Comment: You'd have to go via `.api`, then talk directly to the pywin32 object to do any table related stuff, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html